# Alternative to bluetooth beacons?

Tags: android, ios, swift, flutter, bluetooth

Hello I'm not too sure if this is the best place to ask this question

[image]

I have an iOS Swift app and the client want to determine the location in the mall so using altitude the app have only work on the specific floor for example floor number 3

I tried to use Beacon but I guess this old school way

I wonder if there's the alternative of beacon or a better solution I'm not sure anything will be useful

thank you

Comment: If you search for the term Real-Time Location Systems (RTLS), or sometimes called Indoor Positioning Systems (IPS) then you should find lots of discussion on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

iBeacons can work very well. If you only need to know when the user approaches your client's store you should be able to solve it with beacons just in their store.

If you want to track users' locations throughout the mall you will need to get agreement from either all the stores or store management to place beacons regularly throughout the mall so you can approximate user's locations. (One in every store's window would be ideal.)

Comment: That sound good but the beacon is old I hardly to find some code example for it, to ensure I'll read more about beacon thank you

Comment: If all you want is "Customer is approaching client's store" then one beacon would work. You'd set up a beacon geofence in Core Location. You can set it up so your app will be launched when the user enters range of the beacon.